# Is there an implementation of cost curve in Scikit-Learn?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics, data-visualization

I would like to know if the cost curve is implemented in Scikit-Learn to get the features (thresholds, normalized expected costs and probability cost function) required to draw such curve, and then calculate its AUC.

Cost curves are an alternative to the commonly used ROC curves.

They analyse classification performance by varying operating points. Operating points are based on class probabilities and misclassification costs (see p5 of http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article/file?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0118432&type=printable).

Thanks, Alexandra